# xline option when date is formatted %th?

Tags: stata

I'm doing a connected twoway plot with x-axis as dates formatted as %th with values 2011h1 to 2017h2. I want to put a vertical line at 2016h2 but nothing I've tried has worked.

`xline(2016h2)`
`xline("2016h2")`
`xline(date==2016h2)`
`xline(date=="2016h2")`

I'm thinking it might be because I formatted dates with

```
gen date  = yh(year, half) 
format date %th
```

I think this is a MWE:

```
age1820 date
10.42   2011h1
10.33   2011h2
11.66   2012h1
11.01   2012h2
14.29   2013h1
10.95   2013h2
12.42   2014h1
7.04    2014h2
7.07    2015h1
6.95    2015h2
4       2016h1
8.07    2016h2
5.98    2017h1
3.19    2017h2
```

`graph twoway connected age1820 date, xline(2016h2)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your example will not really work as written without some additional work. I think in future posts you may want to shoot for a fully working example to maximize the chance that you get a good answer quickly. This is why I made up some fake data below.

Try something like this:

```
clear
set obs 20  
gen date = _n + 100
format date %th
gen age = _n*2
display %th 116 
display %th 117
tw connected age date, xline(116 `=th(2018h2)') tline(2019h1)
```

The crux of the matter is that Stata deals with dates as integers that have a special label attached to them by the format command (but not a value label). For example, 0 corresponds to 1960h1. In other words, you need to either:

1. tell `xline()` the number that corresponds to the date you want
2. use `th()` to figure out what that number is and force the evaluation inside `xline()`.
3. use `tline()`, which is smart enough to understand dates.

I think the third is the best option.